# github desktop - how to copy paste branch name

Tags: github, github-desktop

This would be a no-brainer on the command line or web. But in desktop, how do I copy the current branch name?

Just wanted to clone the current branch and use the same name, eg. long-branch-name-2

Answer (score 2):

One simple workaround. Pretend you want to rename. Not obvious at all, but it works well enough.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hope it helps someone else stumbling in frustration. They should probably fix the UI.